# Convert abf to atf file type. Where should I start?

Tags: type-conversion, file-format, file-conversion

I want to preface this question by first saying I am not 100% sure this is the correct place to ask.

Basically, I want to take files with the .abf (axon binary files) extension and convert them to .atf (axon text files). I was wondering if I could simply just run a script that converts binary to text or if it would be more complicated than that.

I'm making a script that takes files with the .abf extension and feeds them into the Clampex9.2 program in order to save them as .atf files. However I feel like there is a much better way than manually feeding the files into a program, then resaving them with the correct extension.

Again, if this is not the right forum for this type of question, I apologize but thank you in advance if anyone can help me with this problem!